# How to change row number in formula with variable?

Tags: excel, vba

```
R=6
Do Until R = LastRow
If (Range("Y" & R)>0) Then
Range("AZ" & R).Formula = "(U17*W17)
```

I want the 17th row to be the current R value. The cell should contain the formula not only the result.
Any idea?

Comment: a) Fully qualify your range references (e.g. `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(...)`); b) a formula assignment receives a string starting with the equal sign `"=....` otherwise it would show only pure text, e.g. `"=U17*W17"` - no need for brackets here; d) assuming you increment your `R` value in the loop, just break the string into parts and concatenate the `R` value via ` & ` to `U` and `W`, similar as you did with `"AZ" & R`. @Zqm

Comment: Your loop body is incomplete, it's not clear what column needs to get the current R value, and the formula should probably get the row number from R instead of being hard-coded. Please [edit] your post to clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want the formula to be?
If you want it to be say "=Y17" where R=17 then

```
If Range("Y"& R).Value > 0 Then Range("AZ" & R).Formula = "=Y" & R
```

Comment: But what if I want =(U*W)/(U+W) each with the Rth row?